# How do I enable deletion protection for load balancer using ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService cdk construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created a Fargate service running on an ECS cluster fronted by an application load balancer using the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService CDK construct.

```
  cluster,
  memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
  desiredCount: 1,
  cpu: 512,
  taskImageOptions: {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),
  },
});
```

There are no Props for enabling deletion protection. Can anyone tell from his experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDK offers the Escape Hatches feature to use Clouformation Props if any High-level construct does not have parameters.

```
// Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public
    var loadBalancedService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, `${ENV_NAME}-pgadmin4`, {
      cluster: cluster, // Required
      cpu: 512, // Default is 256
      desiredCount: 1, // Default is 1
      taskImageOptions: { 
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('image'),
        environment: {}
        },
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024, // Default is 512
      assignPublicIp: true
    });
  
    // Get the CloudFormation resource
    const cfnLB = loadBalancedService.loadBalancer.node.defaultChild as elbv2.CfnLoadBalancer;
    cfnLB.loadBalancerAttributes = [{
      key: 'deletion_protection.enabled',
      value: 'true',
    },
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent to @UmeshTyagi's answer in Python CDK:

```
cfn_lb = self.fargate_service.load_balancer.node.default_child
cfn_lb.load_balancer_attributes = [{"key": "deletion_protection.enabled", "value": "true"}]
```